# How to filter an array of JSON objects with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON input:

```
{
  "zk_kafka": [
    {
      "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
      "zkMemory": "16",
      "kafkaMemory": "8"
    },
    {
      "InstanceType": "t2.small",
      "zkMemory": "8",
      "kafkaMemory": "4"
    }
  ],
  "es_hdfs": [
    {
      "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
      "esMemory": "16",
      "hdfsMemory": "8"
    },
    {
      "InstanceType": "t2.small",
      "esMemory": "8",
      "hdfsMemory": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

First I want to select an array by a property name. And then I want to select an object of the array by the value of the property `InstanceType`.

Example for the property `zk_kafka` and the value `t2.medium`:

```
{
  "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
  "zkMemory": "16",
  "kafkaMemory": "8"
}
```

I know how to select the array:

```
jq .zk_kafka
```

But I do not know how to filter the array of object by a property value.

Comment: Show us your input and expected output, rather than stating an `X-Y` problem

Comment: This time I wrote the question for you, but next time read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 71):

Use the `select` filter of `jq`:

```
jq '.zk_kafka | .[] | select(.InstanceType == "t2.medium")'
```

Use the `--arg` option to pass an argument to the query to avoid injections.

```
jq --arg instance "t2.medium" '.zk_kafka | .[] | select(.InstanceType == $instance)'
```

`jq` has a [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), a [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and a [cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook).

Comment: The quoting works fine. But keep in mind that you have to escape the regular expression according to the requirements of `sed`.

Comment: {
   "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
   "zkMemory": "16",
   "kafkaMemory": "8"
  },
  {
   "InstanceType": "t2.small",
   "zkMemory": "8",
   "kafkaMemory": "4"
  }   this is my block.If matches t2.medium then it should give me entire block and t2.medium will come from variable.In pattern I gave manually t2.medium and it worked but not accepting from variable.

Comment: Why do you want to use `sed`, if you have already `jq`? Forget `sed`. `jq` is all you need. Edit your question. Show complete input and complete command and expected output.

Comment: {
 "zk_kafka": [
  {
   "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
   "zkMemory": "16",
   "kafkaMemory": "8"
  },
  {
   "InstanceType": "t2.small",
   "zkMemory": "8",
   "kafkaMemory": "4"
  }
 ],
 "es_hdfs": [
  {
   "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
   "esMemory": "16",
   "hdfsMemory": "8"
  },
  {
   "InstanceType": "t2.small",
   "esMemory": "8",
   "hdfsMemory": "4"
  }
 ]
}           I want a block from zk_kafka when matches t2.medium.

Comment: expected output is {
                        "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
                        "zkMemory": "16",
                        "kafkaMemory": "8"
                },

Comment: Thanks, its working.I tried some alternatives but this is the best solution

Comment: Technically unrelated but since this is a question people new to `jq` like me will come across: If your filter returns multiple items `jq` will just output them after another. To get an actual list back, you apparently just enclose your command in `[ ]`: `jq '[ .zk_kafka | .[] | select(.InstanceType == "t2.medium") ]'`

Comment: What if I want to update the value of any property in the returned node, in fact, updating the original JSON string after filtering?

Comment: @shzyincu You need to use the update assignment operator [|=](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment).

Comment: @ceving if i have an array and I have to update and nested property on a condition of its parent sibling node?

Comment: @shzyincu Maybe you should write a question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use `map()`:

```
jq '.zk_kafka | map(select(.InstanceType == "t2.medium"))' input.json
```